# Kendo tree view remote data all nodes load initally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

i have been using kendo tree view for navigation purpose in my mvc project and all my datas are coming from db i had made remote binding to tree view and data bind is perfect.but the problem is i got only the first node and on expanding the first node all its child node are loading i want all the child node to loaded on the time of page load.is there any way to do it .here is my kendo control

```
@Html.Kendo()
   .TreeView()
   .Name("myThings")
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
       .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Employees"))
    ).DataTextField("Name")
```

and my controller code is

```
var employees = _context.Employees
    .Where(e => id.HasValue ? e.ReportsTo == id : e.ReportsTo == null)
    .Select(e => new {
           id = e.EmployeeID,
           Name = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
           hasChildren = e.Employees1.Any()
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI documentation on `TreeView` configuration property [`loadOnDemand`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/treeview#configuration-loadOnDemand) says:

> Indicates whether the child datasources should be fetched lazily when parent groups get expanded. Setting this to false causes all child dataSources to be loaded at initialization time. Note: when initializing the widget from an array (rather than from a HierarchicalDataSource instance), this option defaults to false, rather than true.

Consider using it.